# When would Kosaraju's algorithm be a better choice than Tarjan's for strongly connected components?

Tags: depth-first-search, connected-components

I know both have runtime complexity $\mathcal{O} (V+E)$, but [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) does a **single** DFS pass, whereas [Kosaraju's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) does **two** DFS passes. Both need extra space (e.g. a dynamic set, often a stack, for the former to keep track of low links, and e.g. a linked list for the latter to do the second traversal in decreasing finish time order from the first traversal).

I often see textbooks (e.g. CLRS) describing [Kosaraju's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) instead of [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm). Maybe that's for pedagogical reasons, but I wonder if there is something else to it.